# Initializing function in LL

Tags: c, struct, initialization

If I have the following structure defined:

```
typedef struct bear_t { 
    char* name;
    void (*eat)(struct bear_t* this); 
    void (*drink)(struct bear_t* this); 
    void (*sleep)(struct bear_t* this); 
    void (*study)(struct bear_t* this); 
    void (*live)(struct bear_t* this); 
    void (*dtor)(struct bear_t* this); 
    int health;
    int happiness; 
} bear_t;
```

In a bear_t* create_bear(void) method, I want to do the following:

- Create a new bear with malloc
- Initializes the bear’s eat, drink, sleep, and live functions to the default values (eat_fish, drink_water, sleep_lots, live).
- Initializes the study function to NULL, since default bears don’t know how to study.
- Initializes the bear’s health and happiness to 0.
- Initializes the bear’s destructor (dtor) field to delete_bear.
- Sets the bear’s name to “bear” (bear->name=”bear” is sufficient).
- Returns the bear to the caller.

How would I initialize the functions?

Comment: In C there is no direct way. If you change these function pointers as static, then you can assign it in the definition itself. Otherwise you have to create a wrapper function/macro to create an object

Comment: That's going to depend on whether you want to zero any other fields, or what other initialization you plan to do.

Comment: What about the other members?  If setting them all to NULL is acceptable, then you can just do `bear_t bear = { 0 };`.

Comment: You can use constructor or some other initialization function according to your need.

Comment: Is `bear_t fozzy = new bear_t;` a bad answer? If it isn't then it would be a easything to do. `fozzy->name="fozzy bear"`

Comment: @WeatherView This is clearly C. A member called `dtor` which destroys the object is perfectly validly described as a destructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing particularly complicated about initializing function pointers:

```
void eat_fish(struct bear_t* this)
{
    this->happiness += 42;
    this->health += 23;
}
void drink_water(struct bear_t* this)
{
    this->happiness += 10;
    this->health += 12;
}
// ....

bear_t* create_bear(void)
{
    bear_t *bear = (bear_t*)malloc(sizeof(bear_t));
    bear->name = "bear";
    bear->eat = &eat_fish;
    bear->drink = &drink_water;
    bear->sleep = &sleep_lots;
    bear->live = &live;
    bear->study = NULL;
    bear->dtor = &delete_bear;
    bear->health = 0;
    bear->happiness = 0;
    return bear;
}
```

As a side note, please not that this kind of Object-Oriented coding in plain C-style is really not a simple way to do things. If you're actually trying to get into C++ (as the tags to the question would suggest), try sticking to the "ordinary" way of doing these kinds of things, which would be using (virtual) member functions.

Comment: The OP tagged it as C.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like homework, but anyway, here is one way:

```
bear_t* create_bear(void)
{
    bear_t const default_bear = 
    {
         .eat = eat_fish;
         .drink = drink_water;
         .sleep = sleep_lots;
         .live = live_the_life;
         .dtor = delete_bear;
         .name = "bear";
    };

    bear_t *new = malloc( sizeof *new );
    *new = default_bear;
    return new;
}
```

Any fields you don't mention in the initializer list get set to zero or null pointers.

---

You should think a bit about `char *name` as it is not clear who is responsible for allocating memory for `name`.  If it is only meant to be used with string literals then change it to `char const *name`.

If the name might be changed then either make it an array,  or make it point to dynamically-allocated space (which `delete_bear` will have to know to free). For the latter case, take `.name` out of `default_bear` and add a line just before `return new`:

```
new->name = strdup("bear");
```

(or `malloc` plus `strcpy` if you don't have strdup available).